# Can I replace MariaDB with MySQL in Bitnami MAMP?

Tags: mysql, macos, mariadb, mamp

I am maintaining an old, large CakePHP project which relies on the JSON database column type. This type is supported by MySQL but **not** by MariaDB. Changing out the JSON type is not a practical option.

I have been relying on the Bitnami MAMP stack to run this project, but after upgrading I discovered that there's no longer an option to run MySQL in the newer versions.

Is there a way of manually swapping out MariaDB for MySQL?

I am relying a lot on PhpMyAdmin for database admin tasks, so I need this to connect correctly as well.

I already tried the option of running the MacOS built-in Apache and MySQL installs, but it seems very hard to get this setup to run in a reliable way, and when asking for advice people seem to think it's not a great option. The Bitnami packaged MAMP stack, on the other hand, runs really well. It's just this compatibility issue that messes things up for me.

Is it possible to keep things running smoothly and only swap out the database part of the stack?

Many thanks.

Comment: you can't swap it, but nothing holds you back to installing mysql on port 3307, then you can transerf the database with any tool you like. the ports can after copying beswapped.

Comment: Can you upgrade the MariaDB instance? As of 10.2.7 it supports the JSON data type https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/

Comment: @Nick actually all it does is substitute JSON with a text field ("longtext"). In my case this unfortunately doesn't help, since what I need is for the database adapter to be able to save and read objects. This happens automatically with the JSON type, but not with text fields.

Comment: @nbk that sounds like a good option, but I can't seem to get it to work. I set the built in instance to run on port 3307 using my.cnf and stopped MariaDB, but now there is no database connection. Would you know what the steps would be to make this work? Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted what your issue was.

Comment: Can't you convert the object to/from a JSON string (e.g. using `json_encode` and `json_decode`) before writing to the database? Or if you're not actually using the database `JSON` functions, `serialize`/`unserialize`?

Comment: @Simon you have also change the port in phpmyadmin and the connectionstring to 3307, you can aölso have in phpmyqadmin two server one on 3306 and the second 3307 no problem, if a server is not running you must chekc the mysql error log, also did you run the mysql_secure _installation?

Comment: @Nick you are right, this would in theory be fine, but unfortunately I have a large, existing codebase and it would be a tricky process to convert all the existing read/write operations where the conversion currently is supposed to happen automatically.

Comment: @nbk the missing database connection is between my PHP application and MySQL. Still working on this, if you have any pointers for how to make sure MySQL is running on the correct port that would be amazing. Thank you also for the tip about editing the connection string to get PhpMyAdmin hooked up. That will be my next step.

Answer (score 0):

I went down many rabbit holes trying to find a good solution and ended up with the following. (Reminder that this is on Mac OS, in my case Catalina.)

1. Do a normal MySQL installation (you will get a MySQL icon in System Preferences)
2. Configure the PHP application to use host `127.0.0.1` (not localhost) and port `3306`
3. Install a second PhpMyAdmin instance (in my case at /phpmyadmin-mysql)
4. Create a config.inc.php file in the PhpMyAdmin root directory.

The file should have the following settings.

```
$i = 0;
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
```

I can now use either MySQL or MariaDB over the same Apache instance by just setting the host and port number.